# Write an SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a fetch results from a table that have employee and spouse. If an employee have spouse then the employee and spouse should complete a survey or if an employee don't have spouse the employee must complete the survey. the survey is in another table 'survey' and the completion status code is '3'. The employee and the spouse data are in the 'user table', the are identified by their id ie, employee have id 10000 and if that employee have spouse then the spouse id is 10001. Can you help me to fetch the results.

User table is

```
id, user_id, firsyt_name, last_name, email, status, date
```

survey table

```
survey_id,user_id,title, content,date, flag
```

if user id is AE10000 then spouse is AE10001

My attempt so far:

```sql
    select m.first_name,m.user_id 
    from user m 
        LEFT JOIN survey tp ON m.user_id=tp.user_id AND tp.status=3 
        LEFT JOIN user sp 
            on LEFT(sp.user_id, -1) = LEFT(m.user_id, -1) 
            and sp.user_id = left(m.user_id, -1) || 1 
            and sp.status = 'Y';
```

[image: Survey table]

[image: user table]

I just need the employee details, not the spouse details but if the employee has spouse then the spouse should complete the survey and if the employee doesn't have spouse then the user should complete the survey.

The output i want is : user_id, first_name, last_name, email

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: How do you identify an employee in this table (you give us one hard coded example). What if the employee id is `AE10094` is the spouse `AE10095`? Please share some more sample data so we can establish some sort of pattern here. In the end are you trying to load the `survey` table from the `user` table? Do you need to identify whether they are a spouse or employee or can just all the `user` entries go right into the survey table? It's not at all clear what is happening here.

Comment: so far am here

select m.first_name,m.user_id from user m 
LEFT JOIN survey tp ON m.user_id=tp.user_id 
AND tp.status=3
LEFT JOIN user sp on LEFT(sp.user_id, -1) = LEFT(m.user_id, -1)
  and sp.user_id = left(m.user_id, -1)||1
  and sp.status = 'Y';

Comment: The user id will be like AA100500 for spouse AA100501

each  employee id ended with 00 for employee and for spouse 01

Comment: So is it far to say that you just want users where they end in either 00 or 01. Is it important in the output of this sql to specify the person and their spouse in the same record? I think maybe it would help a TON if you provide some sample data and your desired results since it's not clear what exactly the output should look like. Please if you provide that sample data, edit your question and add it there, not in the comments.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by "complete the survey" That is not a SQL function, a result set specification or anything that is in context here. What do you want this data to look like when it is pulled? What is the output? You have two tables that are inputs, but no example of what the output should look like. "Complete the survey" or not doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Don't write everything in uppercase letters. This does not make your text more important and besides that, all uppercase is generally considered as shouting.

Comment: Complete the survey means the flag in the survey table is 1, 0 is for incomplete survey.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will return you the list of user with maritial status and the spouse id. Can you do the rest from this output?

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(A.user_id,LEN(A.user_id)-1)+'0' user_id,
CASE 
    WHEN B.u_id IS NULL THEN 'Married' 
    ELSE 'Unmarried' 
END Status,
CASE 
    WHEN B.u_id IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE B.u_id + '1'
END Spouse_id
FROM [user] A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT LEFT(user_id,LEN(user_id)-1) u_id
    FROM [user]
    WHERE RIGHT(user_id,1)  = '1'
)B ON LEFT(A.user_id,LEN(A.user_id)-1) = B.u_id
```

Output will be-

```
user_id     Status      Spouse_id
A100010     Unmarried   A100011
A100020     Married     NULL
A100030     Married     NULL
A100040     Unmarried   A100041
```